# Why is require.main.filename different on Azure that it is on my local windows machine?

Tags: node.js, azure

On my local machine, this code:

```
var path = require('path');
var appdir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
console.log(appdir);
```

will log "c:\sites\mysite"

On Azure, I see this instead: D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode

I know, from [setting the node version to be my own](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/specifying-a-node-version/) that the path to my app is D:\home\site\wwwroot

And, according to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) "the entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking require.main.filename."

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your application on your local machine you probably execute following command

```
node.exe your_application.js
```

That is why [`require.main.filename`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module) returns the entry point of your application.

Please note that when you deploy your application to Windows Azure WebSite you use [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) - a native IIS 7/8 module that allows hosting of Node.js applications in IIS 7/8. That is why `require.main.filename` returns `D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode` on Windows Azure.

I would recommend using [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) module local variable (usually combined with [`path.join()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) e.g. `var mydir = path.join(__dirname, '..')`) in order to obtain required directory.

I hope that explains your question.

Comment: Yes . . . that makes sense! Sure would be nice to get to the root of the application instead of where node was started but it turns out I got it to work with relative paths which I suppose is the "right" way. Thanks!