# Pattern for if(require.main) that works on Azure's iisnode

Tags: node.js, iisnode

A pattern [seen in both Node](http://heyrod.com/snippet/s/nodejs-require-main.html) and Python development that allows a module to be used both standalone and as a module looks like this:

```
function main() {
    // ....
}

if(require.main === module) {
    main();
}

module.exports = {
    start : main
}
```

Unfortunately, this [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456876/why-is-require-main-filename-different-on-azure-that-it-is-on-my-local-windows-m) on Microsoft's Azure cloud service, as `iisnode` overwrites require.main with *something else* (not sure what). How can I rewrite the check to work on Azure as well, starting the main module if it is the main entry point?

Answer (score 0):

I only found a hackish solution to this problem, which basically detects whether I am running iisnode or not:

```
var onIISNode = require.main.filename.match(/iisnode/);
if(onIISNode || require.main === module){ ... }
```

Improvements are welcome ... especially ones actually using the official Azure API for NodeJS